# Populate list view when a page is just visited in windows RT app using C#

Tags: c#, listview, windows-store-apps

I am trying to populate a list view containing names of different animals from a file. I cannot figure out which event to wire up to in order to populate the list view just as the particular page is navigated to. Since I am reading the values from a file using an async method , I wonder if that can be some source of problem.

```
 private async void pageRoot_LoadedAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      try
        {
            await GetNameOfAllAnimalsAsync();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {

        } 
    }

 private async Task GetNameOfAllAnimalsAsync()
    {
        var animalIo = new AnimalIo();
        var animalNames=await animalIo.GetAllAnimalNames(DateTime.Now);
        if (animalNames != null)
        {
            foreach (var animalName in animalNames)
            {
                if (itemListView.Items != null) 
                    itemListView.Items.Add(animalName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Right now I am using the page load event. This does not populate the names in the list view. It only shows black boxes. Further when the page is loaded the second time, the names are shown but the selected item is always null.

I am a newbie, so please pardon incorrect usage of terms. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using foreach, try this code

```
ItemListView.Items = animalNames;
```

About your code, probably the main issue is IF expression, check if Items not null

Comment: I do not have access to Visual Studio and typing from tablet, that is why I can not check the code, but anyway trying to give you main idea, how to solve your question. Can you try this one itemListView.ItemsSource = animalNames;

Answer (score 0):

Converting from the OnLoaded to the OnNavigatedTo worked for me. This was my code:

```
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
       {
            try
            {
                await GetNameOfAllAnimalsAsync();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {

            } 

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

      }
```